# Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379// while using docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, redis, celery

This may be a simple question but I've just started to learn docker and I am making my first project with it.

I have a django project using celery and Redis. I've made Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libffi-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    net-tools

ARG PROJECT=djangoproject
ARG PROJECT_DIR=/var/www/${PROJECT}

RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR

WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 8000
STOPSIGNAL SIGINT
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: rd01
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '6379'

  django:
    container_name: django_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: docker_tutorial_django
    volumes:
      - ./parser_folder:/var/www/djangoproject
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - celery

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A Parsing worker -B --loglevel=DEBUG
    volumes:
      - ./parser_folder:/var/www/djangoproject
    links:
      - redis
```

When I execute *docker-compose up* I get an error **consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379//: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address..**

I tried to change ports and write the command for Redis in docker-compose.yml but it won't working. Help me to figure it out please

Comment: Your redis instance runs on `redis` not on `localhost` => `redis://redis:6379/`